# Recursively remove .php .htaccess & Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've set up a Wordpress site. 
I need to recursively remove the .php extension on files in a specific folder.

Say:
**www.domain.com/wordpresspage/** (set up with permalinks, all good).

I then need to remove .php recursively for folder:
**domain.com/gz/***

The content of **domain.com/gz/** should have the .php extension removed. But only for this folder.

**Folder structure**

```
/
-/images (No .htaccess rules should apply, Wordpress takes care of it.)
-/downloads (No .htaccess rules should apply, Wordpress takes care of it.)
-/gz (.htaccess change, to remove .php file extension, overwriting Wordpress, in this particular folder)
-file1 (No .htaccess rules should apply, Wordpress takes care of it.)
-file2 (No .htaccess rules should apply, Wordpress takes care of it.)
```

Before I used the following .htaccess content to remove .php extensions, but now I need to only force this on one folder, since Wordpress is taking care of the rest.

```
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.php\ HTTP
#RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
#RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

I've tried a ton of things already, but the last few included:

1. Use the old .htaccess file that removes .php on all pages. This solves my path issue, but gives internal server error on the rest of the site.
2. Tried a gazillion ways of filtering out that folder recursively, to the point I'm no longer sure if it's even possible. (Don't even remember a fraction of what I tried).
3. Tried in the permalinks to add .php - but since it will redirect to remove it again, I'll get yet another Internal Server Error.

TL;DR - Can I recursively remove .php on a specific path in my .htaccess file, so Wordpress ignores this folder and let's it deal with it's own business?

**Added after first round of help, my .htaccess file now looks like this:**

```
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

RewriteEngine On
# Only apply if request starts with /gz/
# followed by at least one character and ends with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?gz/[^.]+\.php$
# Redirect to the same location but without .php ant the end
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Only apply if request starts with /gz/ followed by at least one character
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?gz/[^.]+$
# and the request it not a real directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and the request it not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite the request with .php at the end
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

AddType application/x-httpd-php-old .php

<IfModule security_module>
  SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule security2_module>
  SecRuleRemoveByID 1-99999
  SecRuleRemoveByTag unoeuro
</IfModule>
```

After re-applying **Permalinks**, Wordpress adds this section to the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance,

L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is the following

```
RewriteEngine On
# Only apply if no rewrite
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# Only apply if request starts with /gz/
# followed by at least one character and ends with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?gz/[^.]+\.php$
# Redirect to the same location but without .php ant the end
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Only apply if request starts with /gz/ followed by at least one character
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?gz/[^.]+$
# and the request it not a real directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and the request it not a real file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite the request with .php at the end
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

So if you request e.g. /gz/gz5.php is will be redirect you to to /gz/gz5
and if the request is /gz/gz5 it will rewite to /gz/gz5.php